# Letras aleatórias: Como gerar com rand e como compará-las em C

Tags: c, random, números-aleatórios

Estou tentando criar um vetor de char de 10 posições, quero alimentá-lo com 10 letras aleatórias e ordenar decrescentemente com Bubble Sort. Minha dúvida é: o rand gera characteres aleatórios assim como gerar números, ou tem alguma diferença? eu posso compará-los usando < e >?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
void armazenaAleatorios(char vetor[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        vetor[i]=rand()%26;
        printf("%c  ",vetor[i]);
    }
}
void bubble_sort(char vetor[], int tamanho){
    int i, j;
    char aux;
    for(i=tamanho-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        for(j=0;j<i; j++){
            if(vetor[j] > vetor[j+1]){
                aux = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1] =  aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
void apresenta(char vetor[]){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%c  ",vetor[i]);

    }
}
int main(){ 
    //int vetor[5] = {5, 9, 10 ,50 ,1};
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    char vetor[10];
    armazenaAleatorios(vetor);
    bubble_sort(vetor,10);
    apresenta(vetor);
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: para gerar caracteres aleatorios basta gerar números menores que 256

Comment: Não, isso não resolve. Queria deixar meu código certinho, mas sua edição foi rejeitada. Como eu exibo o código identado?

Comment: voce precisa identar o código com  4 espaços ... acredito que o atalho seja ctrl K

Comment: Se voce estiver falando de caractere com apenas letras do alfabeto basta voce tirar o resto por 26 na função rand e somar com o caractere 'A'. (Isso vai gerar apenas letras maiúsculas no vetor)

Comment: Se vc tiver o DEVc++ testa aí. Não está funcionando

Comment: vetor[i]=rand()%26 + 'A';

Comment: Se voce olhar a tabela ascii os valores das letras maiúsculas vao de 65 para 90 ... entao se voce gerar um numero aleatório menor que 26 e somar com 65 (ou caractere 'A') ... voce vai gerar um numero que corresponde a uma letra

Comment: Como as letras sao numeros ... voce pode usar < ou > para ordenação

Comment: Cara, simplesmente muito obrigado! Fiquei um tempão aqui quebrando cabeça pra entender isso, com sua explicação e uns vídeos que vi aqui deu pra entender tudo. Vlw!

Comment: parabens =) ... eu sou meio ruim pra explicar mesmo kkkk

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está funcionando perfeitamente, só faltou somar 'a' em cada char do vetor. E o seu bubble sort está ordenando em ordem crescente e não decrescente. Pra mudar isso é só trocar o > para < no if. Aqui vai o código funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void armazenaAleatorios(char vetor[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        vetor[i]= 'a' + (char)(rand()%26);
}
void bubble_sort(char vetor[], int tamanho){
    int i, j;
    char aux;
    for(i=tamanho-1; i >= 1; i--)
        for(j=0;j<i; j++)
            if(vetor[j] < vetor[j+1]){
                aux = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1] =  aux;
            }
}
void apresenta(char vetor[]){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%c  ",vetor[i]);
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
}
int main(){ 
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    char vetor[10];
    armazenaAleatorios(vetor);
    bubble_sort(vetor,10);
    apresenta(vetor);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Seu programa estava retornando caracteres malucos pois você estava escrevendo os caracteres de 0 a 26, que representam caracteres de controle e não são imprimíveis. O código da letra 'a' é 97, 'b' é 98 e assim por diante, portanto é só você somar 97 no vetor[i], que fica tudo certo. Colocando 'a' o compilador já vai substituir por 97 automaticamente. As duas linhas a baixo são equivalentes:

```
vetor[i]= 'a' + (char)(rand()%26);
vetor[i]=  97 + (char)(rand()%26);
```

Para gerar um char aleatório, basta usar o rand() e converter o int obtido para char, isso é feito colocando (char) na frente do que você quer converter. Se você não colocar ele vai converter automaticamente, mas é sempre bom colocar no código porque fica claro que a conversão está acontecendo!

Valores char são números! Um char tem um byte e representa um número de -127 a 128, então comparações podem ser feitas normalmente como se fosse um número! Repare que se você mudar o `printf("%c",vetor[i])` para `printf("%d",vetor[i])` o %d vai imprimir o número que está guardado no char. A diferença é que o %c pega o número, consulta na tabela ASCII e imprime a letra que equivale aquele número! Por exemplo se o char contiver o número 97, o %c vai imprimir um 'a'. De uma olhada na tabela ASCII para ajudar:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Você pode até mesmo usar um char dentro de um for:

```
char i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    vetor[i]= 'a' + (char)(rand()%26);
```

Isso vai funcionar da mesma maneira! Mas se for usar um char pra isso lembre-se que o seu limite é 128 ! A maioria dos compiladores utiliza o char com valores entre -127 e 128, mas em alguns o valor é de 0 a 255, pois o padrão não define exatamente qual usar. Se for usar o char como número melhor especificar unsigned char.

Espero ter ajudado :)